# Show that $(\sum_{j=1}^l \sqrt{\delta_{j-1}^2 - \delta_j^2}\psi_j)_{l\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show that $$(\sum_{j=1}^l \sqrt{\delta_{j-1}^2 - \delta_j^2}\psi_j)_{l\in \mathbb{N}}$$ is a Cauchy sequence for some inner product that induces a norm, where $(\psi_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal system and $(\delta_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence with $\delta_j \gt 0 \forall j\in\mathbb{N}, \lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \delta_j = 0$.

My attempt:

For $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ $$\sqrt{\langle \sum_{j=1}^m \sqrt{\delta_{j-1}^2 - \delta_j^2}\psi_j, \langle \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\delta_{i-1}^2 - \delta_i^2}\psi_i \rangle}$$

Using the orthonormal system and the bilinearity of the inner product I get:

$$\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n \langle \sqrt{\delta_{j-1}^2 - \delta_j^2}\psi_j, \sqrt{\delta_{i-1}^2 - \delta_i^2}\psi_i \rangle}$$

$$ = \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^m \delta_{j-1}^2 - \delta_j^2} = \sqrt{\delta_0^2 - \delta_m^2}$$

I was hoping that this would result only in $\sqrt{\delta_m^2}=\delta_m$, so that I could use the convergence of the delta sequence to create an N that would let me show that this is a Cauchy sequence, but the $\delta_0$ doesn't disappear, making it impossible to show that it is a cauchy sequence.
I have run over the derivations multiple times and can't find an algebraic mistake, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are manipulating that expression to begin with. Let's write $a_j = \sqrt{\delta_{j-1}^2-\delta_{j}^2} \psi_{l}$, then you want to show that the sequence $b_{l} := \sum_{j=1}^{l} a_j$ is Cauchy with respect to the inner product. This means that $\|b_{l}-b_{m}\|^2 \to 0$ for $l,m \to \infty$. WLOG assume $l>m$, then we obtain
$$\|b_{l} - b_{m}\|^2 = \left\|\sum_{j=m+1}^{l}a_{j}\right\|^2 = \left\|\sum_{j=m+1}^{l}\sqrt{\delta_{j-1}^2-\delta_{j}^2} \psi_{j}\right\|^2 =
\sum_{j=m+1}^{l}(\delta_{j-1}^2-\delta_{j}^2) \|\psi_{j}\|^2\ \\ =\sum_{j=m+1}^{l}(\delta_{j-1}^2-\delta_{j}^2) =\delta_{l}^2 - \delta_{m}^2  $$
where I've used the pythagorean theorem for inner product spaces and the fact that the $\psi_{j}$ are orthonormal. This expression goes to $0$ as $n,m \to \infty$ because $\delta_{j} \to 0$.

Comment: Apparently, not a problem, but I think that $\psi_l$ has to be $\psi_j$. Anyway, please, can you explain the last step?

Comment: @RafaBudría yes that's right, it should be $\psi_j$. We have $\|\psi_{j}\| = 1$ so it's just a telescopic sum.